# How to invoke a link using href or anything from my java method?

Tags: java, struts, href, struts-1

I need to invoke the href link on my java method. My sample code is defined below. After finishing my logic i need to invoke the URL. The URL is used to open an Excel workbook and import our bean values to there.

```
public void populateExcelReportValues(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
        String METHOD_NAME = "populateExcelReportValues";
        log.entering(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);

        //Rating Element Id 
        String ratingElementIdForExcel = request.getParameter("ratingElementIdFromJSP");
        //Instance Type Name
        String instanceTypeForExcel = request.getParameter("instanceTypeFromJSP");
        int ratingElementIdForExcelInt = 0;

        String instanceTypeValueForExcel = "";
        if(ratingElementIdForExcel != null && ratingElementIdForExcel.trim().length()>0)
        {
            ratingElementIdForExcelInt = Integer.parseInt(ratingElementIdForExcel);
            System.out.println("ratingElementIdForExcelInt: "+ratingElementIdForExcelInt);

        }
        if(instanceTypeForExcel != null && instanceTypeForExcel.trim().length()>0)
        {
            instanceTypeValueForExcel = instanceTypeForExcel.trim();
            System.out.println("instanceTypeValueForExcel: "+instanceTypeValueForExcel);
        }
        switch (ratingElementIdForExcelInt) 
        {
            case 1: //ASN Accuracy - Rating Element ID - 1 
                    weeklyDeliveryInstancesRatingElementQO = getASNAccuracyRatingElement(instanceTypeValueForExcel);
                    //return weeklyDeliveryInstancesRatingElementQO;
                    break;
            default:
                    weeklyDeliveryInstancesRatingElementQO = new ArrayList<WeeklyDeliveryInstancesRatingElementQO>();
                    break;
        }
        //How to invoke this url to here
        **(MultiTableExportServlet?multitablesId=WeeklyDeliveryInstances-Count&amp;name=WeeklyDeliveryInstances-Count&amp;type=excel)**
        log.exiting(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME);
    }
```

In above my code i showed to bold for your identification.

### Jsp page:

```
<display:table name="${weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.asnAccuracyListQO}" uid="asnAccuracyListUID" sort="list" defaultsort="1" 
                                        requestURI="/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPre.do?method=httpGet" excludedParams="method"
                                        decorator="com.ford.mpl.superg.decorator.WeeklyDeliveryInstancesTypeTableDecorator" keepStatus="true">
                                        <%@include file="/jsp/include/displaytag.jsp"%>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.firstWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.secondWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracySecondWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.thirdWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyThirdWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.fourthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyFourthWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.fifthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracyFifthWeekOfCount"/>
                                        <c:set value="${asnAccuracyListUID.sixthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="asnAccuracySixthWeekOfCount"/>

                                        <c:choose>
                                        <c:when test="${asnAccuracyListUID.instanceTypeDescription != null && asnAccuracyListUID.instanceTypeDescription != 'Sum'}">
                                            <display:column property="instanceTypeDescription" title="Instance Type" sortable="false"/>
                                        </c:when>
                                        <c:otherwise>
                                            <display:column property="instanceTypeDescription" title="Instance Type" sortable="false" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center"/>
                                        </c:otherwise>
                                        </c:choose>


                                        <display:column property="firstWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFirstWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"/>
                                        <display:column property="secondWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracySecondWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  />
                                        <display:column property="thirdWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyThirdWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  />
                                        <display:column property="fourthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFourthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" />
                                        <display:column property="fifthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracyFifthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" />
                                        <display:column property="sixthWeekOfCount" title="${asnAccuracySixthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"/>
                                    </display:table>
                                </fieldset>

                                <export:multitables id="WeeklyDeliveryInstances-Count">
                                        <export:table title="tablename" source="${weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.weeklyDeliveryInstancesRatingElementQO}">
                                            <export:column property="shipCode" title="Ship Code" />
                                            <export:column property="plantOrRecLoc" title="Plant/Rec Loc" />
                                            <export:column property="instanceType" title="Instance Type" />
                                            <export:column property="fordOrg" title="Ford Org" />
                                            <export:column property="OrgType" title="Org Type" />
                                            <export:column property="region" title="Region" />
                                            <export:column property="shipDate" title="Ship Date" />
                                            <export:column property="errorTransmitted" title="Error Transmitted" />
                                            <export:column property="externalAlertNo" title="External Alert Number" />
                                            <export:column property="asnNumber" title="ASN Number"/>
                                            <export:column property="packingSlipNumber" title="Packing Slip Number"/>
                                        </export:table>
                                    </export:multitables>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect the user's request to a servlet in your webapp called MultiTableExportServlet? Or do you mean you want to call this servlet from your Java code and then carry on processing the user's request e.g. using your Struts Action class?

Comment: @martin,i want to redirect the multitableexportservlet from my java method

Comment: What's the servlet-name in servlet-mapping for your MultiTableExportServlet servlet in web.xml? Is it multitableexportservlet?

Comment: @martin, servlet name is MultiTableExportServlet

Comment: What's its url-pattern in servlet-mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take this approach:

In struts-config.xml add a forward to the servlet in your action, for example:

```
<forward name="Success" path="/servlet/MultiTableExportServlet"/>
```

(You'll need to change 'path' to the url-pattern of your servlet if it is different from above).

In your Action class you can redirect to this forward by doing this:

```
    ActionForward originalForward = a_mapping.findForward ("Success");  
    String path = originalForward.getPath() 
        + "?multitablesId=WeeklyDeliveryInstances-Count&name=WeeklyDeliveryInstances-Count&type=excel";     

    ActionForward forward = new ActionForward(path);
    forward.setRedirect(true);
    return (forward);
```

Your query string  (multitablesId=WeeklyDeliveryInstances-Count etc) looks wrong. Is WeeklyDeliveryInstances-Count a variable? I can't see where you define or use it.

Comment: after forwarding to that servlet the list is null. I don't know y it occurs.but i check the list it have the value before the forward function....

Comment: What list? If that's a request attribute then it will be lost with a redirect.